# Should custom suggested edit reject reasons be presented in the inbox?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

It takes time to write custom review messages.  Usually this is a good clue that someone took time and did a good review.  For instance, when I was newer I tried [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1811231), which was approved, but Lukas's comment set me in the right direction.

People often click nonsensical **canned** review reasons; I believe because they think the reviewed person will never view them and it would take too long to type out the real reason.  Many new users are not aware of the *activity|suggestions|suggested edit* sequence to find the custom reasons.  Obviously, this has the potential to be abused, just as regular comments do.  However, I think that custom review reasons to *suggested edits* are helpful in correcting behavior that might be outside any **FAQ** or canned reason.  That fact that the custom reasons make it to a user, may encourage reviewers to take the time to type in custom reasons instead of clicking some *canned* reason that may not be appropriate, even though they have good reason to **reject**.

NB: The inbox is the thing at the top navigation beside the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider  SuperDropdown™.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When people are new, they don't always know how to see comments for rejections, and there is no way to know who is trying to be helpful versus who is only trying to gain reputation points in their edits. I agree that custom comments should be delivered to a user's inbox so that new users will at least have ideas from the reviewers on their radar.

Of course, that only helps if the reviewers say, "Hey, why not make a tag cleanup request? Here's how:" instead of "quit making mass edits", which I didn't find helpful (and didn't notice right away either) when I was making a series of edit requests that were small but useful.

**Delivering messages to the inbox would potentially help new users who are genuinely interested in learning about how to participate meaningfully on Stack Overflow.**

Answer (score 1):

I have asked a couple of questions about how to do reviews here on Stack Overflow. One style of answer is that I could write custom comments but these answers suggest that doing so may be a waste of my time. Perhaps that view is partly because the comments are often not read by the person who they are directed at.

I expect that that is partly because new users do not know where to find the comments. If such comments were positively sent to the user then the comment authors would have some satisfaction that the comments could be easily found and may be useful. Of course some people will not read them or will ignore them, but hopefully some would find them useful.

Answer (score 0):

While I do see where you're coming from, I think not showing what other people have voted may be the least worst solution. While it's true that a custom reason may indicate they were paying attention, they may also be mistaken and cause the same robo-reviewers to assume they were right and quickly reject it without verifying either way.

Comment: Nothing will stop real robo-reviewers.  The real ones won't take the time to read anything.  The main issue is to stop non-sense reasons (like plagiarism) when the real reject reason is different; that is the specific rational for *custom*, yet as the other answers say *people recommend not to bother as no one will see them*.  Thanks for reading the question/comment and taking the time to answer.